# Storing Image to remote server using Http Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to display Image and store Image on remote server.I am using Ibm Worklight Version 6.2.I Have gone through many links but didn't find the solution

My HTML Page code is

```
<fieldset style="height:auto;width:100% ">

                    <div id="Image" style="float:left;">
                        </div>
                        <div id ="delImage">                
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

and my Js Code is

```
    uploadImage =  function (){
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCallBack, onFailCallBack, { 
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
};

  function onSuccessCallBack (imageData){
   var img  =   document.createElement("img");
    img.style.width = "60px";
    img.style.height="60px";

    img.src =  imageData;

    var Image = document.getElementById("Image");
    Image.appendChild(img);

    var delImg  =   document.createElement("img");
    delImg.style.width = "60px";
    delImg.style.height="60px";

    delImg.src  =  "images/brws_gal.png";

    var deleteImg = document.getElementById("delImage");
    deleteImg.appendChild(delImg);




    var invocationData      =   {
            adapter         :   'DisbursalRequestImageAdapter',
            procedure       :   "uploadImageForDisbursal",
            parameters      :   [ requestObject, sessionId, operationFlag,'','' ]

    };
    var options             =   {
            timeout         :   timeout,
            onSuccess       :   successCreateImg,
            onFailure       :   failureCreateImg
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);

};
```

Here, I am appending Dynamic Image in a div.
My Question is

1. I want to store the image to remote server using Http Adapter
2. I want to open the picture on the click of Picture.
3. I am not arrange the div vertically i.e. every time the photo is taken a new div should be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an image to a remote server, you need to base64 encode the image and then send this string to be stored in the remote server's database.

If you want to then retrieve it you need to get the string and then decode the base64 string back to an image filetype and display the image in your HTML (the image should be stored in the device storage using Cordova APIs as you have demonstrated use of).

In fact, had you searched, the above is what you would've found in searches.

Comment: I totally Agree with you Idan, I just want to know how can i encode the Image Into Base 64 as I am only getting ImageData In which only the Image URI is coming.

Comment: I got it If i Replace FILE_URI with DATA_URL i will get the picture automatically in Base 64 format and an sent it to remote server